# Looking up list keys in a Raku set

Tags: raku

In Raku, I can create a set of lists:

```
> my $set = SetHash.new((1, 2), (3, 4, 5))
SetHash((1 2) (3 4 5))
> $set.keys.map(&WHAT)
((List) (List))
```

But I can't seem to check for the existence of a list key:

```
> $set{(1,2)}
(False False)
```

...because the list in the subscript is interpreted as a slice, not as a single key.

Is there any way to look up such a key?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sets work on ValueTypes.  Even though a List may seem like a ValueType, unfortunately it is not (because although the number of elements in a List is fixed, it may contain mutable elements, and is therefore *not always* a constant).

That's why I implemented the [Tuple](https://raku.land/zef:lizmat/Tuple) module a few years ago already.  This allows you to:

```
use Tuple;
my $set := SetHash.new: tuple(1,2), tuple(1,2,3);
say $set{tuple(1,2)};  # True
```

Granted, a bit verbose.  You can shorten the verbosity by re-defining the `tuple` sub:

```
use Tuple;
my &t := &tuple;
my $set := SetHash.new: t(1,2), t(1,2,3);
say $set{t(1,2)};  # True
```